# Поиск слова в строках файла и вывод этой строки вместе с 2мя последующими

Tags: python, файлы, текст

Есть файл или список файлов, нужно найти строку которая содержит слово или его часть и вывести 3 строки. Строку с найденным файлом и следующие 2.

Пример файла:

```
qwertyprivetqwerty
str1
str2

uffuffuffuff
struff
struff

qwertyprivetQWERTY
strQ
strQ
```

Слово которое ищем: privet

Ожидаемый вывод:

```
qwertyprivetqwerty
str1
str2

qwertyprivetQWERTY
strQ
strQ
```

Comment: А если `qwertyprivetQWERTY \n qwertyprivetQWERTY \n strQ \n strQ`? Два блока по 3 строки? 1 блок 3 строки? 1 блок 4 строки?

Comment: @Akina, не очень Вас понял. Весь файл содержит одинаковый вид.                              
  `строка \n строка \n строка \n \n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Пример:***

```py
WORD = 'privet'


def main():
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        rows = f.readlines()

        for i in range(len(rows)):
            if WORD in rows[i]:
                strings = rows[i:i+3]
                print(*strings, sep='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
qwertyprivetqwerty
str1
str2

qwertyprivetQWERTY
strQ
strQ
```